# SQL Code to add QTY's and display only latest entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find a way to calculate all QTY's from the invoices (`ShippedQTY`) for a specific part and return only the latest Invoice number based on Createdate for that part number with the total shipped QTY for the current day.

```
Current Code:

select SUM(CAST(ASNDetail.ShippedQty AS INT)) AS ShippedQty, asndetail.partnumber, 
ASNMaster.SupplierInvoiceNo,
asnmaster.createdate
from ASNMaster (nolock) inner join  ASNDetail (nolock) ON ASNMaster.RecordID = ASNDetail.ASNMasterId
WHERE ASNMaster.OwnerId = '966'  AND PartnerId in ('3057') and CreateDate >= '2019-10-22' -- This should display the latest date only. I'm assuming a 'MAX' can be used for this?
GROUP BY ASNDetail.PartNumber,ASNMaster.SupplierInvoiceNo,ASNDetail.ShippedQty,ASNDetail.ReleaseMasterID,asnmaster.createdate
ORDER BY ASNDetail.PartNumber ASC

Current Output:

ShippedQTY  partnumber      SupplierInoiceNumber        Createdate
36         AB39 2624623 AE      2SI051746          22/10/2019 10:01:29 PM
24         AB39 2624623 AE      2SI051747          22/10/2019 10:01:29 PM
12         AB39 2624623 AE      2SI051753          22/10/2019 10:05:30 PM
40         AB39 26278A98 AD     2SI051742          22/10/2019 10:11:29 AM
16         AB39 26278A98 AD     2SI051743          22/10/2019 10:12:30 PM
24         AB39 26278A98 AD     2SI051752          22/10/2019 10:05:29 PM

Required Output: 

ShippedQTY    partnumber       SupplierInoiceNumber     Createdate
72          AB39 2624623 AE         2SI051753       22/10/2019 10:05:30 PM
80          AB39 26278A98 AD        2SI051743       22/10/2019 10:12:30 PM

I Need to sum all the shipped quantities for that specific part number and 
return the total shipped quantity and latest Invoice Number. Please note Invoice
numbers differ. I also need to return only shipped quantities for today ie 
MAX(createdate)
```

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms used. (Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. (And take a look at [mcve].)

Comment: @marcelporteus . . . The "output" does not match the query.  Just look at the columns.

Comment: @marcelporteus . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.  You can also set up a db fiddle of some sort.

Comment: Edited my code above to try and make the requirement more clear. Apologies, this is the first time I've used Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions and filter in the subquery:

```
SELECT TOP(10) m.ShippedQty, 
       d.PartNumber, d.ShippedQty, d.ReleaseMasterID
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             SUM(CAST(d.ShippedQty AS INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY OwnerId, PartnerId, SupplierInvoiceNo) AS ShippedQty,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.OwnerId, m.PartnerId, m.SupplierInvoiceNo ORDER BY d.<datecol> DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ASNMaster m
      WHERE m.OwnerId = 966 AND m.PartnerId in (3057)
     ) m INNER JOIN
     ASNDetail d
     ON m.RecordID = d.ASNMasterId
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, there is no <datecol> in the detail. This would have to be taken from ASNMaster.

Comment: I only want to display today's values based on createdate from ASNMaster